# Kinect SDK 2: CoordinateMapper not returning valid results

Tags: kinect

I understand that calling a mapping function should be very simple but on debugging the following code the ColorSpacePoint values are often -1.#INF0000. The CameraSpacePoint which I pass to the mapping method is fine. Anyone have any ideas why this is the case? Thanks.

```
    _sensor = KinectSensor::GetDefault()

    //Do some stuff

    CameraSpacePoint pos3d = body->Joints->Lookup(t->JointType()).Position; // This works.
    ColorSpacePoint pos = _sensor->CoordinateMapper->MapCameraPointToColorSpace(pos3d);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments of the CoordinateMapperBasics Sample Project:

> //The sentinel value is -inf, -inf, meaning that no depth pixel corresponds to this color pixel.

So it will be a valid value for Color pixels with a corresponding depth pixel, but you should perform a check to make sure the value isn't negative infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my issue - it's a pretty specific one but there's always a chance someone else might run into this.

I use Microsoft's Kinect Studio to pipe a performance to my applications. This works beautifully however you must select which data-streams you wish to pass. By default the 'Nui Uncompressed Color' stream is not bundled with the rest. Without this all calls to the colorframe mapper will be invalid.

Simply adding the uncompressed color stream to the kinect data solves this issue. However I often need to stop/restart the stream to get the mapper to work. Not sure why that is.